# Need help in Regex pattern- C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string which has a word "provided" and may or may not have the word "deadlock".

I need regex pattern in C# for two scenarios:

1. The string must contain both "provided" and "deadlock".
2. The string must contain "provided" but not "deadlock".

So I need two regex pattern for this

I tried  `(?.*provided).* ^(?!.*deadlock).*$`
But this didn't help me.

Comment: why not use the contains function instead of Regex?

Comment: Basically you need to check if `provided` exists. Checking whether `deadlock` exists is redundant. Think about it, you don't need regex at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string must contain both "provided" and "deadlock".

```
^(?=.*deadlock).*provided
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The string must contain "provided" but not "deadlock".

```
^(?!.*deadlock).*provided
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks for the reply... In my string "provided" will be coming first and then comes "deadlock". So will that be a matter in this pattern??

Comment: @user3719370 Ulugbek's solution will work regardless of the order +1 :)

Comment: Thanks. I used that. but its not matching the string.
The string which i have contains the word "provided" in it but not "deadlock". Once the pattern is matched using Regex.Match(mystring,pattern), the result of "Match.Success" is false.

Comment: and if i use [^(?!.*deadlock).*provided], the strings that doesn't have "provided" or "deadlock" are also matching.

Comment: @user3719370 Read the answer properly please. `[^(?!.*deadlock).*provided]` was **never** mentioned.